# How can I add components to gameobject?

Tags: unity, c#

```
foreach(Component comp in components)
            {
                myother.AddComponent<comp>();
            }
```

I'm getting error on the comp on the line :

```
myother.AddComponent<comp>();
```

'comp' is a variable but is used like a type

What I'm trying to do is a simple teleporting script.

The problem I faced is that the object I'm trying to teleport have some components : Animator, NavMeshAgent , Rigidbody , Box Collider , and a script that move the object(character) to the first teleporter and then teleport the object to another teleporter.

In my scene I have some doors and when I'm changing the alpha color of the object to 0 and then change the object position to the other teleporter the object collide and stuck in one of the doors. I'm not sure what component/s make the problem so I decided to destroy the components from the object make the teleporting and then add back the components :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleporting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> teleporters = new List<GameObject>();
    public GameObject objectToTeleportMaterial;
    public float fadeSpeed = 0.1f;
    public bool toTeleport = false;

    private List<Vector3> teleportersPositions = new List<Vector3>();
    private bool teleporting = false;
    private bool teleported = false;
    private Material material;
    private GameObject myother;
    private List<Component> components = new List<Component>();


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        teleporters.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Teleporter"));

        if (teleporters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (GameObject teleporter in teleporters)
            {
                teleportersPositions.Add(teleporter.transform.position);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        myother = other.gameObject;
        material = objectToTeleportMaterial.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        TeleportingVisualEffect(material, 0f, 5f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(teleporting == true)
        {
            foreach (var comp in myother.GetComponents<Component>())
            {
                if (!(comp is Transform))
                {
                    components.Add(comp);

                    Destroy(comp);
                }
            }

            myother.transform.position = teleporters[0].transform.position;
            TeleportingVisualEffect(material, 1f, 5f);
            teleporting = false;
        }

        if(teleported == true)
        {
            foreach(Component comp in components)
            {
                myother.AddComponent<comp>();
            }

            teleported = false;
        }
    }

    private void Teleport(GameObject objectToTeleport)
    {

    }

    private void TeleportingVisualEffect(Material material, float fadeTargetOpacity, float fadeDuration)
    {
        MaterialExtensions.ToFadeMode(material);
        StartCoroutine(FadeTo(material, fadeTargetOpacity, fadeDuration));
    }

    // Define an enumerator to perform our fading.
    // Pass it the material to fade, the opacity to fade to (0 = transparent, 1 = opaque),
    // and the number of seconds to fade over.
    IEnumerator FadeTo(Material material, float targetOpacity, float duration)
    {

        // Cache the current color of the material, and its initiql opacity.
        Color color = material.color;
        float startOpacity = color.a;

        // Track how many seconds we've been fading.
        float t = 0;

        while (t < duration)
        {
            // Step the fade forward one frame.
            t += Time.deltaTime;
            // Turn the time into an interpolation factor between 0 and 1.
            float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

            // Blend to the corresponding opacity between start & target.
            color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);

            // Apply the resulting color to the material.
            material.color = color;

            // Wait one frame, and repeat.
            yield return null;
        }

        if (targetOpacity == 0)
        {
            teleporting = true;
        }
        else
        {
            teleported = true;
        }
    }

    private Material GetMaterial(GameObject ObjectToTeleport)
    {
        Material material = null;

        if (ObjectToTeleport.GetComponent<Renderer>().material != null)
        {
            material = ObjectToTeleport.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        }
        else
        {

            foreach (Transform child in ObjectToTeleport.transform)
            {
                if (child.GetComponent<Renderer>().material != null)
                {
                    material = child.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
                }
            }
        }

        return material;
    }
}
```

I have two flags : teleporting and teleported. When teleporting is true I'm destroying the components then when teleported is true I'm trying to add back the components I kept in a List name components.

This screenshot is showing the blue teleporter with the character near it. 
When running the game the character is moving to the teleporter :

[image: Character near the first blue teleporter]

and this is the green teleporter. The green teleporter is in another room and area in the scene :

[image: Green teleporter]

and this is when the character teleported and stuck/collided with a door and position there instead on the green teleporter :

[image: Character in door]

Things I know so far :

1. If the green teleporter will be in the same room near the blue teleporter it will teleport the character without a problem.
2. If the green teleporter is in another place area in the scene and there are doors on the way the character will collide and stuck in the door/s.
3. If I destroy all the components from the character it will be teleported fine even if the green teleporter is in other area in the scene.

Comment: You can use AddComponent to generate a new component of a specific type and add it, but you can not add an instance of a component you already have. Can you take a step back and tell us what you are actually trying to accomplish here and why?

Comment: @Philipp I will edit my question.

Comment: Lol, if this isnt't a case of an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) I don't know what is. I recommend you wait for someone to post an answer on your previous question.